# PhpStorm: possible to update file template on each file edit?

Tags: templates, phpstorm

My `PhpStorm 2017.2` project requires that each new file be created from a specific. In *"Settings >> Editor >> File and Code Templates >> PHP File"*, I have the following template:

```
<?php
/**
 * @author John Doe
 * @copyright ${YEAR} Acme
 * @created ${DATE}
 * @modified ${DATE}
 */
```

This works well. PhpStorm fills in the year and date dynamically. However, when I later come back and make changes to the file, I always need to remember to change the `@modified` line manually.  Is there a way to automate this so that onSave or onCommit (for version controlled file), the line is updated with the current value of `${DATE}`?

Comment: Templates are "static". Which means: once it used in a file (Code Template: e.g. to create PHPDoc for a class) or to create a file (File template) the text is now has no "links" to original template as it's just a text in a file.

Answer (score 2):

Not possible ATM.

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEABKL-7178 -- watch this ticket (star/vote/comment) to get notified on any progress. Right now there are no plans to implement something like that in nearest future.

On another hand (as mentioned in the comment in aforementioned ticket) -- see if standard "Copyright" plugin will be of any help (never used it myself so no idea of what exactly it can do).

---

**One possible solution** involves writing your own script/program (PHP or whatever other language you can use) that will parse your file (regex matching should do fine here -- no real need into going and parsing file into tokens) and update such info:

- look at each line until the matching line will be found (some guard logic can be added to limit the number of lines to be parsed: if no matching line is found in first xx (e.g. 20) lines then assume that this file has no such comment/line);
- update date/time part based on file modification timestamp.

Once you have such script -- just use File Watcher functionality so it gets called on each file modification.

**Possible downside:** File Watcher gets triggered when file modification is detected ... which *may* include changes made outside (e.g. another editor/download from remote host/another VCS branch/etc)). This *may* lead to unnecessary/unwanted updates.

If File Watcher functionality is not suitable for whatever reason -- look into `grunt -watch` or alike where you may easily disable watching (so your script will only be called when your watcher (build runner) is watching).

Comment: Thanks as always for taking the time to answer.